# Way to avoid ctrl+F5 to get latest changes on web page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, knockout.js

I have developed SPA  using Knockout. I use Visual studio 2012 for development. My application connects to WCF services and displays the data. I make changes to my application  and deploy on test server. 
When i type url and load application, it shows the old contents on the web page. I have to press ctrl+ F5 to get the latest changes.
Why is it so and what is the way to avoid it? Cant we just press F5 and get the latest changes?
Please let me know what other information you need.

Comment: See http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm

Comment: @Curt Please can you explain more. Didnt understood quite well. Do you mean to say there is no way than to hit ctrl+ F5?

Comment: the issue is with your browser, and it is storing your page in your cache.  I'm sure that if you poke around in the options you can make it stop doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Disable caching in your browser to stop it caching the old page.

Comment: Definitely the best way to get rid of those refresh problems in dev environment !

Comment: @codran we can disable caching programatically, am i correct?

Comment: @AshReva You could try using an HTML5 cache manifest to tell the browser not to cache anything "programatically"-ish.

Comment: @codran can you provide any link?

Comment: @AshReva Googling it will give you a bunch of guides. Here's the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5) for it.